# Populate a tableview with contacts from the addressbook in Xcode 4.3

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode4.3

I'm making an app for iPad and iPhone. in the first screen you need to log on, this works. but then i come to the next screen witch is a tableview. i want this view to be al the names (first name and last name) off the adresbook on the iPad or iPhone.

i get the tableview, but it's empty. can somebody help me?

this is my controller (.m, i don't need to edit the .h):

```
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AddressBook/AddressBook.h"

@interface TableViewController ()
@end

@implementation TableViewController
{
NSMutableArray *ListOfItems;
}

@synthesize tblContacts;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[self ListContacts];
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[self setTblContacts:nil];
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:   (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (IBAction)Back:(id)sender{
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)ListContacts{
/*ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate( );
CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople( addressBook );
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount( addressBook );

for ( int i = 0; i < nPeople; i++ )
{
    ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( allPeople, i );
    UITableView ContactList 
} */

ListOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[ListOfItems addObject:@"Iceland"];
[ListOfItems addObject:@"Greenland"];
[ListOfItems addObject:@"Switzerland"];
[ListOfItems addObject:@"Norway"];
[ListOfItems addObject:@"New Zealand"];
[ListOfItems addObject:@"Greece"];
[ListOfItems addObject:@"Rome"];
[ListOfItems addObject:@"Ireland"];

self.navigationItem.title = @"Countries";
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}

// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section         {
return [ListOfItems count];
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Set up the cell...
NSString *cellValue = [ListOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.text = cellValue;

return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
}

@end
```

notice that i tried to fill my table with some hardcoded values. but again, my table stays empty. Please help.

Comment: Can you use the AddressBook API?

Comment: I think the problem might be `cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];` try initialize it with a different frame

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
@interface AddressBookViewController: UIViewController <ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate> {}
-(IBAction) btnClicked:(id)sender;
@end
```

This is the AddressBook api to access the contacts application from your own application. Maybe you can use it and it'd be much quicker than to implement your own UITableView and all.

Hope it helps.

Comment: yes thank you, but i still can't fill my tableview. it displays without any data..

Comment: [ListOfItems count]; What does that return?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the table's delegate and datasource? You can do it easily through Interface Builder:

1. Select the table view in Interface Builder.
2. Go to the Connectors Inspector of the right bar (the last tab, where you link Outlets and Actions).
3. Link the Data Source and Delegate outlets to the File's Owner (or the file which has the info an methods to manage the table view).

Remember to specify your own class in the File's Owner Identity Inspector (again, in the right  bar of Xcode, third tab).

Hope this helps you!

Comment: By the way, when you do: 'cell.text = cellValue;' I think you're doing it wrong. Your "cell" must have a property of type UILabel, which has a property "text", but you're assigning your string to a "text" property of your cell directly, not a UILabel. You see?

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.textLabel.text = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
```

and make sure you set the identifier in the attributes to Cell.

Answer (score 0):

This is a year later, but hopefully this will help someone:

It looks like you commented out some very important code underneath your `ListContacts` method.

Remove the `/*` and `*/` under -`(void)ListContacts` and your code should at least return some values.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [self.tableView reloadData]; after add data in objects